# Finding probability that a person gets $7$ when rolling a pair of dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability

*I STILL DON'T GET THE ANSWERS PROVIDED. PLEASE HELP!
In a game, the participant rolls a pair of dice. If the result is a $7$, he wins. If the outcome is a number $n$ different from $7$, he continues rolling the dice over and over again. If he gets $7$, he loses. If he gets another $n$, he wins.

- Find the probability that the participant wins this game?
- Find the probability that his final roll will be a $7$?
- Let $A$ denote the number of times the participant wins and $B$ denote the number of times he got a $7$. suppose he has played $100$ games, what are the means and standard deviations of $A$ and $B$?
- Calculate $P(A\geq 77)$
- Calculate $P(B\geq77)$

both of the last questions assume that he plays this game $100$ times.

I personally think we need to use TWO-STAGE Experiment method to solve this problem
i think it's necessary for me to clarify this a bit. for example, if he gets 7 on the first try, he wins. now if he gets 6 on the first try, he continues rolling the pair of dice until he gets 6 again (he wins) or he gets 7 (he loses). this is called crapless craps game.
the probability of getting 7 in a roll is 6/36, of getting 6 or 8 is 5/36, of getting 5 or 9 is 4/36, of getting 4 or 10 is 3/36, of getting 3 or 11 is 2/36, of getting 2 or 12 is 1/36. i don't know where should I go next. i think we need some conditional probabilities here since there are many stages in getting the probability of winning this game

Comment: What are you asking us to do (note that there is no question in your post)?

Comment: i think we have 5 questions clearly. i.e the first question is to find the probability that the participant wins this game.

Comment: Objection, your Honor! We have 5 *orders*. And not an ounce of personal take from your part on the problem.

Comment: sorry i don't want to cause any offense or objection here. all i want to do is to get through this problem. since it's a part of a famous problem and i'm trying to get it solved, i posted it here if anyone can help. anyway, i'm sorry if i don't use proper language here.

Comment: What did you try to solve them?

Comment: I'm confused about that game. If he rolls a 7 on the first try, he wins. Otherwise, he rolls again. If he gets a 7, he loses, if he doesn't get a 7 he wins. From how it's described here, it seems like that always ends after two rolls. @Henry, Can you clarify?

Comment: @CommonerG : I think he means that if the number that was first rolled appears again before a 7 is rolled, he wins.

Comment: @CommonerG: if he gets 7 on the first try, he wins. now if he gets 6 on the first try, he continues rolling the pair of dice until he gets 6 again (he wins) or he gets 7 (he loses).

Answer (score 1):

Draw up a tree of the possible outcomes in the game.

- 1/6 chance of a 7 (direct win)
- 1/36 chance of a 2 -> roll again and keep rolling until 2 or 7

  - 2a. The relative chance of a 2 vs a 7 is 1:6 -> 1/7 chance of a win, 6/7 of loss.
- 2/36 chance of a 3 -> keep rolling

  - 3a. Relative chance 3 vs 7: 2:6 -> 2/8 chance of win, 6/8 chance of loss.
- etc...

Sum up all the ways you can win:
$p_{win}=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{36}*\{\frac{1*1}{7}+\frac{2*2}{8}+\frac{3*3}{9}+\frac{4*4}{10}+\frac{5*5}{11}\}=\frac{6557}{13860}\approx0.47$

Sum up the ways your final roll is a seven:
$p_{seven}=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{36}*\{\frac{1*6}{7}+\frac{2*6}{8}+\frac{3*6}{9}+\frac{4*6}{10}+\frac{5*6}{11}\}=\frac{9613}{13860}\approx0.69$

When you consider 100 independent games we should consider a binomial distribution to evaluate the mean and standard deviation. We have $E=np, SD=\sqrt{n(1-p)p}$, so after getting some numerical results:

$E_{win}=47.3, SD_{win}=5.0$ and $E_{seven}=69.4, SD_{seven}=4.6$

As for the probabilities of winning/ending with seven at least 77 times: for this you need to either evaluate the cumulative distribution function exactly or do some approximation. With Mathematica I calculate the likelihood as $P(x \ge 77)=1-CDF[dist,76]$ to be: $P(A\ge 77)=1.25*10^{-9}$ and $P(B\ge 77)=0.058$.

Comment: what really confuses here is the way we sum up the probability of winning in each branch of the tree. for example, we get 1/36 chance of getting a 2 at the first roll. so the probability of winning in this branch is (1/36)(1/36) + (35/36)(1/36) + ....

Comment: Once you have rolled that two you only have to consider rolls of 2 or 7 to terminate the game. The relative chance of that is 1:6, so the chance of winning at that point is $\frac{1}{36}\times\frac{1}{7}$

Comment: "... winning at that point..." in my comment really should be "... winning in that branch..."

Comment: i'm still confused about your reasoning. for example at the first roll, we get 2. the second roll we get 3 and the third roll we get 2. so the probability of winning at this brand is (1/36).(1/36) + (1/36).(2/36).(1/36)

Comment: You could branch the tree to infinity if you do it that way but you don't have to. For instance, first roll is that 2, then you have a long stretch of 3s or anything other than 2 or 7. They don't matter for the outcome, only a 2 or 7 will terminate the sequence - that's why I consider the *relative* chance of those outcomes.

Comment: It is similar to this problem - you want to generate uniform random integers in the range 1-4. If you don't have a four sided die on hand, just roll a 6-sided one and ignore all fives and sixes (just re-roll until you get something in the range you are interested in). Try to convince yourself that this procedure produces a uniform distribution of integers 1 to 4, then go back to the comment before this one...

Comment: i see your point now. do you think A and B are independent? or positively (negatively) correlated?

Comment: They are almost complementary except for the fact that rolling 7 in the first try is a win. As you can see $p+q=1+\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: why (2/36)*{(1*1)/7 + (2*2)/8 + ...}? shouldn't it be (2/36)*{1/7 + 2/8 + ...}?

Comment: Are you still with me?

Comment: i got it now. thanks